# Nginx rewrite rules for all vhosts

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a huge referer blacklist with that I want to stop referer spam on all my websites (https://perishablepress.com/blacklist/ultimate-referrer-blacklist.txt).

Currently I have to change all my vhost files under /etc/nginx/sites-available/

But this seems quite hard to maintain.

Is there a way or nginx mod which helps me to set the rewrite rules on a central place so that I don't have to maintain them in each vhost file?

I searched all default mods and wasn't able to finde one which meets my requrements.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/include